# trouble understanding calling an F# function

Tags: function, recursion, binding, f#

I'am quite new to F#, and was solving some basic exercises when i stumbled upon this function

1. Give the (most general) types of g1 and g2 and describe what each of these two functions
   computes. Your description for each function should focus on what it computes, rather
   than on individual computation steps

```ml
    let rec g1 p = function 
    | x::xs when p x -> x :: g1 p xs
    | _ -> [];;
```

i don't the understand " when p x " part, or how to call the function. can someone please explain what this function takes in as an argument? as just calling the function like that " g1 [1;2;3] " gives me an error.

Tried calling the function, and tried reading some text books to figure it out

Comment: [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching).

Answer (score 0):

The `function` keyword is a bit tricky, but it's just [syntactical sugar for a `match` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions). The following two functions are equivalent:

```ml
let fooMatch x = 
    match x with
    | 1 -> "one"
    | _ -> "not one"

let fooFunction =
    function 
    | 1 -> "one" 
    | _ -> "not one"
```

If you use `function` instead of `match`, then the (last) argument to the function becomes implicit, rather than explicit, but it's still there. Both versions of `foo` take one argument.

The `when p x ->` part is called a [guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions#guards-on-patterns). In your case, `p` stands for "predicate" (a function that returns true/false). To call your function, you need pass both a predicate and a list. E.g. `g1 (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) [1;2;3]`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. this made much more since for me than my textbook.

Comment: Happy to help out. Please accept the answer (or the other one) to show that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

so this is clearly homework, so I don't want to answer it in full just give guidance.

```
let rec g1 p = function 
    | x::xs when p x -> x :: g1 p xs
    | _ -> [];;
```

is tricky because "function" is sort of shorthand sort of hides a parameter, the above is the same as (well almost, but for your purposes it is).

```
let rec g1 p ys = 
    match ys with
    | x::xs when p x -> x :: g1 p xs
    | _ -> [];;
```

so you can immediately see g1 is a function that takes 2 parameters and returns something

```
g1 : ? -> ? -> ?
```

you just need to try and work out if there is anything more you can infer anythng about the ?s.

So F# will look at your implementation and try and infer what it can.

as said by brian, "when p x" is a guard, so p is a function that takes an x and returns a bool

```
p : ? -> bool
```

and p is the first param of g1 so

```
g1 : (? -> bool) -> ? -> ?
```

etc.
(just be aware you/the F# compiler may not be able to identify a concrete type, like 'bool', sometimes it will infer that it doesnt know the specific type i.e. the function is has a 'parametric' type (generic), so you can get types like

```
identityFunction : 'a -> 'a
```

i.e. whatever the type of the thing being passed in, something of the same type will be returned

2nd note is, this function is recursive, so you have to make sure that the types in the recursive call inside the function line up with the types of the function you infer by inspecting the code)